# Electrical characteristics for high-side switch

Tags: integrated-circuit, datasheet, high-side

[Ref](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps281c30.pdf?ts=1681918217913&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FTPS281C30%253FkeyMatch%253DTPS281C30%2526tisearch%253Dsearch-everything%2526usecase%253DGPN)

1. What is the role of K<sub>CL</sub>

Previously, when I encountered this parameter, it was used in calculating the value of R<sub>CL</sub>, but it only had a single value eg say, 2500.
Could you explain the role of K<sub>CL</sub>

[image]

2. The fault is asserted when I<sub>LIM</sub> is asserted for a duration higher than say deglitch time. Then fault becomes LOW (indicating a fault).

I didn't understand the below characteristics.
[image]

Say V<sub>SNSFH</sub> does this indicate when FAULT is HIGH (i.e. no issues) then the voltage at the SNS pin would be V<sub>SNSFH</sub>?

Similar logic for I<sub>SNSFLT</sub>?

3. What does the term 'no GND network' mean in this context?
   [image]
   [image]
4. Difference between I<sub>ILIM_OVP</sub> & I<sub>ILIM_OVERVOLTAGE</sub> [*Understood this, pls continue with the other half of this question*]
   [image]

Continuing with this
Both overload and short circuit are conditions where high amt of current would flow. So why have these terms been treated differently, effectively the condition remains the same but why the different parameters?

[image]

Comment: A fraction of Iout (Iout / Kcl) is flowing out of the ILimit pin. The voltage across the connected resistor is measured and compared to a fixed value. A higher resistor value produces a higher voltage at this pin and so the limiter starts at a lower load current.

Comment: What is this fixed value the voltage is compared to?a higher resistance would lead to lesser current so that makes sense. I still didn't get the role of K though.

Comment: Okay so I(Lim) = I(out)/K -> R(lim) = V(lim)*K/I(out)